# Making say command bot owner only

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make my !say command only work for the bot owner. This is what I currently have

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def say(ctx, *args):
    mesg = ' '.join(args)
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    return await bot.say(mesg)
```

The code works but I want to make it so only I (the bot owner) can run the command.

Comment: I am not using classes either. If that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing it this way by adding an if statement

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def say(ctx):
      if ctx.message.author.id =='bot owner id':
      then execute the following code
```

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the decorator [`@is_owner()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=is_owner#discord.ext.commands.is_owner).

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.is_owner()
async def say(ctx):
    your code...
```

Comment: Using `commands.is_owner()` should be the accepted answer, instead of adding your own ID in your code

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it - do comment if this does not work as intended.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner() 
async def say(ctx, *, message):
   await ctx.send(f"{message}")
```

Have fun with your coding! Sorry for the late reply, I was reading old questions and seeked for unsolved issues

(remade)

Comment: I have changed the code and made it more simple

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [`check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check) in the 1.0 docs has the below example (slightly modified.)

```
def user_is_me(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == "Your ID" 

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.check(user_is_me)
async def say(ctx, *args):
    mesg = ' '.join(args)
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    return await bot.say(mesg)
```

[How to find your ID](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-)

Comment: `  File "bot.py", line 162
    return ctx.message.author.id = "206696404347781120"
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`
That is what I now get. I am not the best with Python as I am just starting out.

Comment: @damian I used `=` instead of `==`. Just a typo. Try it again ?